# grepl not looking for special characters in regular expression

Tags: r

I am trying to search for certain function names in a list using `grepl`. I am getting an incorrect answer. Here's what I have

```
a <- "My_Test_Other()"
b <- "Test()"
grepl(b, a)
```

This returns `TRUE`. I am expecting `FALSE`. It seems to ignore the `"()"` characters. Any pointers on how to make this work?

Comment: `grepl(b, a, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: And if you need to use other `regex` symbols in combination, you can escape the special `(` and `)` like `grepl("Test\\(\\)",a)`

Comment: @RichardScriven - that is true, but `()` just translates to a group containing nothing, so it will match everything - `grepl("()", "")` and `grepl("()", "blah")` both return `TRUE`

Comment: Awesome! Using the escape character worked